# Almost increasing sequence coding problem

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a coding problem. The problem is following:

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

For example:

[1,3,2,1] is false

[1,3,2]  is true

I implemented it in Java. The code is as follows:

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    
    int count =0;
    
    for(int i =0; i < sequence.length; i++){
        
        if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i-1]){
            count++;
        }
        
        if(count>1){
            
            return false;
        }
        
        if(sequence[i] <= sequence[i-2] && sequence[i+1] <= sequence[i-1]){ 
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

This is the following error:

Execution error on test 1: Your program had a runtime error.

Any help will be appreciated. It seems a small problem but I can't resolve it.

Comment: When `i=0`, what happens w/ the first `if`?

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop, `i` will be `0` so the first `if` will try to compare `sequence[0]`and `sequence[-1]`. `-1` is not a valid index. Either start your loop at `i=1` or add a special-case for that first iteration. Also: it's a good idea to test code like this locally first (i.e. don't just submit it to the service and look at their output, that's usually less useful than the *real* error message you get locally).

Comment: Change `int i = 0` to `int i = 2` and think *critically* about `sequence[i-2]` and `sequence[i-1]`. Also, try running your own code. Ideally try stepping through it with a **debugger**.

Comment: Nothing in the code says "test 1".   Where did that come from?  What kind of "runtime error"?

Comment: test 1 is the first example [1,3,2,1]

Answer (score 3):

One implementation can be based on remove just 1 element when strictly ascending condition is not achieved.

```
public class TestAlmostIncreasingSequence {

    public static boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) 
    {
        if(sequence==null) return false;
        //mandatory to remove just 1 element, if no one(or more) removed then false
        boolean flag_removed=false;
        for(int i=1, prev=sequence[0];i<sequence.length;i++)
        {
            if(prev>=sequence[i] && flag_removed==false)
            {
                //mark removed 
                flag_removed=true;
            }
            //if element was removed then false
            else if(prev>=sequence[i] && flag_removed==true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //change only if element removed is not the current
                //comparisons will not be done with removed element
                prev=sequence[i];
            }
            //System.out.println(prev);
        }
        //could have a strictly increased arr by default which will return false [1,2,3]
        return flag_removed;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //only for printing purpose
        String arr="";
        
        int s1[] = {1,2,3,1};
        arr=Arrays.stream(s1).mapToObj(t->String.valueOf(t)).
                collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
        System.out.println(arr+"\n"+almostIncreasingSequence(s1)+"\n");
        
        int s2[] = {1,2,3};
        arr=Arrays.stream(s2).mapToObj(t->String.valueOf(t)).
                collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
        System.out.println(arr+"\n"+almostIncreasingSequence(s2)+"\n");
        
        int s3[] = {1,2,3,1,2};
        arr=Arrays.stream(s3).mapToObj(t->String.valueOf(t)).
                collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
        System.out.println(arr+"\n"+almostIncreasingSequence(s3)+"\n");
        
        int s4[] = {1};
        arr=Arrays.stream(s4).mapToObj(t->String.valueOf(t)).
                collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
        System.out.println(arr+"\n"+almostIncreasingSequence(s4)+"\n");
        
        int s5[] = {1,1};
        arr=Arrays.stream(s5).mapToObj(t->String.valueOf(t)).
                collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
        System.out.println(arr+"\n"+almostIncreasingSequence(s5)+"\n");
        
        int s6[] = null;
        arr="null";
        System.out.println(arr+"\n"+almostIncreasingSequence(s6)+"\n");

    }
}
```

Output

```
[1,2,3,1]
true

[1,2,3]
false

[1,2,3,1,2]
false

[1]
false

[1,1]
true

null
false
```

Note: The implementation have a case when the result is wrong `[1,5,2,3]`, just update with one more branch with `removed element=the previous one`(not the current) and check both branched (one true means true)

This should fix the case

```
//method name is misguided, removePrev is better 
public static boolean removeCurrent(int[] sequence) 
    {
        if(sequence==null) return false;
        //mandatory to remove just 1 element, if no one remove then false
        boolean flag_removed=false;
        for(int i=1, prev=sequence[0];i<sequence.length;i++)
        {
            if(prev>=sequence[i] && flag_removed==false)
            {
                //mark removed 
                flag_removed=true;
            }
            //if element was removed then false
            else if(prev>=sequence[i] && flag_removed==true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //compared element will be the current one
            prev=sequence[i];
            
            //System.out.println(prev);
        }
        //could have a strictly increased arr by default which will return false [1,2,3]
        return flag_removed;
    }
```

and use

```
int s1[] = {1,5,2,3};
arr=Arrays.stream(s1).mapToObj(t->String.valueOf(t)).
            collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
boolean result= (almostIncreasingSequence(s1)==false) ? removeCurrent(s1) : true;
System.out.println(arr+"\n"+result +"\n");
```

Output

```
[1,5,2,3]
true (from removeCurrent_branch)
```

Seems one more case is wrong `[5,6,3,4]`, means need to see if `element[i-2]`(only after remove element) is not greater then `current` and 'prev' on last branch.

`6>3 remove 6 (prev=3, 3<4 but [5>4 or 5>3] so false)`

```
public static boolean removeCurrent(int[] sequence) 
{
    if(sequence==null) return false;
    //mandatory to remove just 1 element, if no one remove then false
    boolean flag_removed=false;
    for(int i=1, prev=sequence[0], twoprev=Integer.MIN_VALUE;i<sequence.length;i++)
    {
        if(prev>=sequence[i] && flag_removed==false)
        {
            //mark removed 
            flag_removed=true;
            if(i>=2) twoprev=sequence[i-2];
        }
        //if element was removed then false
        else if(prev>=sequence[i] && flag_removed==true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(twoprev>=sequence[i] || twoprev>=prev)
        {
            return false;
        }
            
        //compared element will be the current one
        prev=sequence[i];
        
        //System.out.println(prev);
    }
    //could have a strictly increased arr by default which will return false [1,2,3]
    return flag_removed;
}
```

Output

```
[5,6,3,4]
false
```

Now, as far as I see all cases seems covered.

Brute force can also generate a solution but will be less optimal.(use a loop to remove an element, sort the result and compare with base)

```
public class TestInc {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int s1[] = {1,1,2,3};
        System.out.println(checkInc(s1));
    }
    
    public static boolean checkInc(int[] arr)
    {
        if(arr==null || arr.length==1) return false;
        
        List<Integer> lst = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        //remove this check if requirement is other(or return true)
        if(checkIfAlreadySortedAsc(lst))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
        {
            List<Integer> auxLst = new ArrayList<Integer>(lst);
            auxLst.remove(i);
            List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>(auxLst);
            sorted = sorted.stream().distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            if(auxLst.equals(sorted))
            {
            //  System.out.println("=");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
            //  System.out.println("!=");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //any ascending sorted list will be the same type if remove one element
    //but as requirement on this case will return false
    //(or don't use method in want other)
    public static boolean checkIfAlreadySortedAsc(List<Integer> lst)
    {
        List<Integer> auxLst = new ArrayList<Integer>(lst);
        auxLst = auxLst.stream().distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(auxLst.equals(lst))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output

```
[1,1,2,3]
true
```

Answer (score 0):

This line would produce an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when i == 0 because it will attempt to access sequence[-1]

```
if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i-1]){
```